# Interacting with a REST API from Clojure

Tags: api, rest, clojure, request

What would be the suggested way to send and receive requests to an external REST API without having to run a web server? I can't seem to find anything about making requests and parsing the resulting JSON. The only thing I have found so far is just the json parsing stuff (using the Cheshire library).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A good library for interacting with an external REST API is [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http), which uses [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)). For JSON, there are a few options: [clojure.data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json) (a core lib) and [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) being some popular ones. The lib clj-http has cheshire as a dependency and has JSON support baked in. Cheshire makes use of [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

For example, using `clj-http`:

```
(ns my.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client]))

(client/put my-url
  {:form-params body
   :content-type :json
   :oauth-token @token
   :throw-exceptions false
   :as :json})
```